# Was Hiro replacing himself when he time traveled?

Tags: time-travel, heroes

In Season 4, episode Acceptance. Hiro repeatedly tries to save a jumper who is on top of his building at work. he keeps coming back to the starting point (getting the call) and then going upstairs to try and talk him down. He does this numerous times. This is perhaps the only time we see Hiro return to the same point over and over again at the exact same moment in time.

**Is Hiro replacing himself everytime he starts over?** Otherwise he should be running into himself each time he goes back.

Clearly it is possible for two Hiros to exist in the same time, because the original future Hiro came back to talk to Peter (while the current Hiro was in Japan).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hiro's ability is the manipulation of time and space, not just time traveling (and/or teleportation).

In the instance you mentioned, he was rewinding time and rewinding himself along with it.
So yes, he was replacing himself, but he retained the memories of the other times he did it.

He can basically do whatever he wants with time (which in my opinion, is a concept that was hugely under used in the series)

Comment: Funnily enough, wasn't this part of his ability shown in the very first episode - he gets a clock to tick backwards?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I remembered as I typed

Answer (score 0):

I viewed it as time moving around him, so its not really time travel. Essential he is master of time and space but for some reason he never did anything really useful except for the Sylar-Sword interaction in the first season.